# How to run WCF service in VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, wcf

I am working on running the wcf service in vscode.

1. Tried building using the dotnet build command and got the below exception

MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Progr
am Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.200\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confi
rm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.200\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplicati
ons\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Researched the above error and found more likely its because wcf is not supported in vscode.

what are the ways we can run wcf service in the VSCODE quickly?

Comment: In fact, WCF is not well supported on Visual Code. You can use this tool to give it a try: [WCF dotnet-svcutil tool for .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x)